# getting exception : Service 'db' wasn't found in the dependency injection container in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

Even after setting "db" in services.php I'm getting above exception.

services.php

```
$di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
    $dbclass = 'Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\\' . $config->database->adapter;
    return new $dbclass(array(
        "host"     => $config->database->host,
        "username" => $config->database->username,
        "password" => $config->database->password,
        "dbname"   => $config->database->name
    ));
});
```

I'm trying to fetch users from my table like this,

```
$user = Users::findFirst(1);
```

That time, it is giving

```
    Service 'db' wasn't found in the dependency injection container in Phalcon
```

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Update::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Here I'm loading my services.php file.

public/index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini as ConfigIni;

try {

    define('APP_PATH', realpath('..') . '/');

    /**
     * Read the configuration
     */
    $config = new ConfigIni(APP_PATH . 'app/config/config.ini');

    require APP_PATH . 'app/config/loader.php';

    require APP_PATH . 'app/config/services.php';

    $application = new Application($di);

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Update 2 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

loader.php

```
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

    /**
     * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
     */
    $loader->registerDirs(
        array(
            APP_PATH . $config->application->controllersDir,
            APP_PATH . $config->application->pluginsDir,
            APP_PATH . $config->application->libraryDir,
            APP_PATH . $config->application->modelsDir,
            APP_PATH . $config->application->formsDir,
        )
    )->register();
```

services.php

```
    use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
    use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlProvider;
    use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt as VoltEngine;
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\Memory as MetaData;
    use Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files as SessionAdapter;
    use Phalcon\Flash\Session as FlashSession;
    use Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventsManager;

    /**
     * The FactoryDefault Dependency Injector automatically register the right services providing a full stack framework
     */
    $di = new FactoryDefault();

    /**
     * We register the events manager
     */

    $di->set('dispatcher', function() use ($di) {
        $dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
        return $dispatcher;
    });

    /**
     * The URL component is used to generate all kind of urls in the application
     */
    $di->set('url', function() use ($config){
        $url = new UrlProvider();
        $url->setBaseUri($config->application->baseUri);
        return $url;
    });


    $di->set('view', function() use ($config) {

        $view = new View();

        $view->setViewsDir(APP_PATH . $config->application->viewsDir);

        $view->registerEngines(array(
            ".volt" => 'volt'
        ));

        return $view;
    });

    /**
     * Setting up volt
     */
    $di->set('volt', function($view, $di) {

        $volt = new VoltEngine($view, $di);

        $volt->setOptions(array(
            "compiledPath" => APP_PATH . "cache/volt/"
        ));

        $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
        $compiler->addFunction('is_a', 'is_a');

        return $volt;
    }, true);

    /**
     * Database connection is created based in the parameters defined in the configuration file
     */
    $di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
        $dbclass = 'Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\\' . $config->database->adapter;
        return new $dbclass(array(
            "host"     => $config->database->host,
            "username" => $config->database->username,
            "password" => $config->database->password,
            "dbname"   => $config->database->name
        ));
    });

    /**
     * If the configuration specify the use of metadata adapter use it or use memory otherwise
     */
    $di->set('modelsMetadata', function() {
        return new MetaData();
    });

    /**
     * Start the session the first time some component request the session service
     */
    $di->set('session', function() {
        $session = new SessionAdapter();
        $session->start();
        return $session;
    });

    /**
     * Register the flash service with custom CSS classes
     */
    $di->set('flash', function(){
        return new FlashSession(array(
            'error'   => 'alert alert-danger',
            'success' => 'alert alert-success',
            'notice'  => 'alert alert-info',
        ));
    });

    /**
     * Register a user component
     */
    $di->set('elements', function(){
        return new Elements();
    });
```

Comment: Ok, its not a case of `$di` because you are declaring it during `services.php`, it is also not a matter (95%) of using require instead of include. Having troubles running your code, if you have possibility to upload full project, it would be helpful. Having no idea whats happening right now, one whats sure my answer was not helpful for that question so I deleted it.

Comment: might be retarted but try setting the port in services.php

'port' => 'some_port'

also try to use an adapter directly instead of doing it dynamically, see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this issue before and the fix was the following:
I had two instances of:
`$di = new FactoryDefault();`
I had one in my index.php and one in my services.php file.
I removed the one in my index.php file, and it got rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

change the order of all the $di calls it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in an Phalcon CLI App. I fixed this by importing the DbAdapter by its namespace to the cli.php

```
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;
```

and adding the below code

```
$di['db'] = function() {
    return new DbAdapter(array(
        "host"     => YOUR_HOST,
        "username" => YOUR_USERNAME,
        "password" => YOUR_PASSWORD,
        "dbname"   => YOUR_DB_NAME
    ));
};
```

before

```
$console->setDI($di);
```