# Exception: Service 'voltService' wasn't found in the dependency injection container

Tags: phalcon

I am trying to replicate the examples in the Volt tutorial [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.1/volt), using the basic example of phalcon [here](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.3/reference/tutorial.html), so nothing complicated.

So I created this app/controllers/PostsControllers like this:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
/*        $post = Post::findFirst();
        $menu = Menu::findFirst();*/

        $post = array("title"=>"The titre");
        $menu = "menu1";

        $this->view->show_navigation = true;
        $this->view->menu            = $menu;
        $this->view->title           = $post["title"];
        $this->view->post            = $post;

        // Or...

        $this->view->setVar('show_navigation', true);
        $this->view->setVar('menu',            $menu);
        $this->view->setVar('title',           $post["title"]);
        $this->view->setVar('post',            $post);
    }
}
```

And its corresponding app/views/posts/index.phtml like this:

```
{# app/views/posts/show.phtml #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }} - An example blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {% if show_navigation %}
            <ul id='navigation'>
                {% for item in menu %}
                    <li>
                        <a href='{{ item.href }}'>
                            {{ item.caption }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>

        <div class='content'>
            {{ post.content }}
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I also registered volt in my bootstrap file (/public/index.php) which looks like that:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlProvider;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt;


// Register an autoloader
$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        "../app/controllers/",
        "../app/models/",
    ]
);

$loader->register();



// Create a DI
$di = new FactoryDefault();

// Setup the view component
$di->set(
    "view",
    function () {
        $view = new View();

        $view->setViewsDir("../app/views/");

        $view->registerEngines(
            [
                '.volt' => 'voltService',
            ]
        );


        return $view;
    }
);

// Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
$di->set(
    "url",
    function () {
        $url = new UrlProvider();

        $url->setBaseUri("/care/");

        return $url;
    }
);



$application = new Application($di);

try {
    // Handle the request
    $response = $application->handle();

    $response->send();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

But when I try to access to `/posts` directory (`localhost/care/posts`) I get the following error:

> Exception: Service 'voltService' wasn't found in the dependency injection container

I checked if Volt service was not already declared in `Services.php` as it is said in a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491025/getting-exception-service-db-wasnt-found-in-the-dependency-injection-contai) but it is not.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this block of code. You are telling your view that it should use the `volt` extension and process it using a service called `voltService`.

```
// Setup the view component
$di->set(
    "view",
    function () {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setViewsDir("../app/views/");
        $view->registerEngines(
            [
                '.volt' => 'voltService',
            ]
        );

        return $view;
    }
);
```

If you look at your snippet, there is no service called `voltService` defined.

However if you add this to your services, it should work:

```
// Register Volt as a service
$di->set(
    'voltService',
    function ($view, $di) {
        $volt = new Volt($view, $di);

        $volt->setOptions(
            [
                'compiledPath'      => '../app/compiled-templates/',
                'compiledExtension' => '.compiled',
            ]
        );

        return $volt;
    }
);
```

Reference: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/volt#setup